# Separate letters in excel from 1 column to different rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I need this way.

[image]

It's not possible to sort the files manually because there are files with triple or quadruple alphabets too. I want it to be one by one alphabetically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also try `TEXTJOIN()` then `MID()` functions-

```
=LET(x,TEXTJOIN("",1,A1:A20),MID(x,SEQUENCE(LEN(x)),1))
```

To refer entire column and ignore empty cells use `TOCOL()`.

```
=LET(x,TEXTJOIN("",1,TOCOL(A:A,1)),MID(x,SEQUENCE(LEN(x)),1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something along the lines of:

[image]

---

```
=TOCOL(MID(A1:A2,SEQUENCE(,MAX(LEN(A1:A2))),1))
```

---

You could wrap within `SORT()` function to get alphabetically as well:

```
=SORT(TOCOL(MID(A1:A2,SEQUENCE(,MAX(LEN(A1:A2))),1)))
```

---

Or You could use the following but usually in this forum, we don't suggest on using `TEXT` functions group to combine a whole range into one single string, because of character limitations, hence why it is avoided and not shared in the beginning.

```
=LET(α,CONCAT(TOCOL(A:A,1)),SORT(MID(α,SEQUENCE(LEN(α)),1)))
```

---

Comment: =TOCOL(MID(A2:A3950,SEQUENCE(,MAX(LEN(A2:A3950))),1)) i used this but it got SPILL

Comment: What do you mean by `SPILL` the formula is meant to be spilled only as it is uses dynamic array formulas. Works absolutely fine on my end.

Comment: You will get a SPILL error if any cell in the resulting list is already occupied. Make sure you use an empty column for the formula.

Comment: @Paul I am aware of the error, I am asking OP to complete their sentence. But thanks for highlighting the point to OP. Since OP is saying but i got `SPILL` which can be two things, either they are trying to say the formula `SPILLS` or they are getting SPILL error, so OP needs to be clear with their statements when they are commenting anything.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Agreed, I was just assuming the second.